# how to solve this symmetrical equation in number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

i just have no idea about this equation, i would thank you to you to give me some suggestions on this.
$$m_{1}m_{2}m_{3}+2^{\alpha-s-t}m_{1}+2^{\alpha-\gamma-t}m_{2}+2^{\alpha-\gamma -s}m_{3}\\-2^{\alpha-\gamma-s-t}-2^{\alpha-t}m_{1}m_{2}-2^{\alpha-s}m_{1}m_{3}-2^{\alpha-\gamma}m_{2}m_{3}+1=0$$
where $3\leq \gamma+s+t\leq \alpha-1,$and all of them are integer numbers.

Comment: for large $\alpha$ and generic $\gamma,s,t$ reduces to cubic equation root solving. where did you get this?

Comment: i have tried in  this way. it seems  a  poor efficiency way.

Comment: It's linear in $m_1$ and you can force the coefficient of $m_1$ to be $1$ by a choice of $m_2,m_3$. That gives one solution. Do you just need a solution or all of them?

Comment: i need all of them.

Comment: i have got an answer:$m_{1}=19,m_{2}=177,m_{3}=111,\gamma=s=1,t=2,\alpha=5.$

Answer (score 3):

It is convenient to define $n_1:=m_1-2^{\alpha-\gamma}$, $n_2:=m_2-2^{\alpha-s}$, and $n_3:=m_3-2^{\alpha-t}$. Then the equation in question takes form:
$$n_1n_2n_3 = (2^{\alpha}-1)(2^{\alpha-s-t}n_1+2^{\alpha-\gamma-t}n_2+2^{\alpha-\gamma -s}n_3) + 2\cdot 2^{3\alpha-\gamma-s-t} - 3\cdot 2^{2\alpha-\gamma-s-t} + 2^{\alpha-\gamma-s-t} - 1.$$

First thing we may notice is that the solutions satisfy a congruence:
$$n_1n_2n_3\equiv -1\pmod{2^{\alpha}-1}.$$

Next, we can construct an infinite series of solutions with $n_3=1$. In this case, the equation can be rewritten as
$$(n_1 - (2^{\alpha}-1)2^{\alpha-\gamma-t})(n_2-(2^{\alpha}-1)2^{\alpha-s-t})= (2^{\alpha}-1)^2 2^{2\alpha-\gamma -s-2t}  +
 (2^{\alpha}-1)2^{\alpha-\gamma -s} + 2\cdot 2^{3\alpha-\gamma-s-t} - 3\cdot 2^{2\alpha-\gamma-s-t} + 2^{\alpha-\gamma-s-t}  - 1.$$
Take any values of $\alpha,\gamma,s,t$ and let $N$ denote the r.h.s. of the above equation. Then for any factor $d$ of $N$, we obtain a solution $n_1=d+(2^{\alpha}-1)2^{\alpha-\gamma-t}$ and $n_2=\frac{N}{d}+(2^{\alpha}-1)2^{\alpha-s-t}$.

---

**Example.** Let $\gamma=s=t=3$ and $\alpha=10$. Then $N=272115953$. If we take $d=971$, we obtain a solution $(n_1,n_2,n_3)=(17339, 296611, 1)$, which translates to $(m_1,m_2,m_3)=(17467, 296739, 129)$.